# How do I type a placeholder React element in another Component in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm having trouble trying to figure out this Typescript error. Here's the code:

```js
interface AppProps {
  Component: JSX.ElementClass;
  pageProps: JSX.ElementAttributesProperty;
}

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  console.log(Component)
  console.log(pageProps)
  return (
    <>
    {globalStyles}
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </>)
}
```

I get the charming error: `JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.` against the 3rd to last line.

My guess is that it is because I'm using `<Component ...` directly as JSX? And it isn't a real type, i.e. it's just the parameter name being used as a stand in for whatever JSX component is actually being handed in? Is it children somehow? In the code I'm actually using a React Fragment to include `<EmotionGlobal/>` and `<Home/>` elements.

Comment: Yeah, just use the children prop with a type of React.ReactChildren | React.ReactChild and use {children} inside your fragment. Instead of passing page props to the App Component, pass them to your corresponding child or children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLease, take a look here:

```
interface AppProps<P> {
  Component: React.JSXElementConstructor<P>;
  pageProps: P;
}

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps<{ data: string }>) => {
  console.log(Component);
  console.log(pageProps);
  return (
    <>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Some explanations:

- Change Component to the proper type - `JSXElementConstructor<P>` where P is the type of props you need
- Make interface AppProps generic
- Type pageProps with generic type P